# awk + gsub + how to work with all kind of characters

Tags: linux, bash, awk

The following `awk` command target is remove spaces and unnecessary  quotes from CSV file and only from single words between separators

```
awk 'gsub(/("[ ]+|[ ]+")/,"\""){$0=gensub(/"([[:alnum:]]+)"/,"\\1","g")}1' file.csv
```

example: ( before )

```
1,"1.0348    54 35.5",""45356",""4"""""35,"578 "
```

example: ( after )

```
1,"1.0348    54 35.5","45356,"4""""35,578
```

the problem is that `awk` can’t handle when characters are non alpha numeric

example

```
1,"  jde7@&^%  "," &^!@  ",)(*&^," (*^%%^&*( "
```

my target is to work with all kind of characters non alpha numeric and alpha numeric

as

```
(  A-Z , !@#$%^&&**( , 1-9 , etc )
```

I guess I need to replace the **[[:alnum:]]** with some other syntax.

What do I need to change  in my `awk` syntax in order to support all kind of characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[[:alnum:]]` character class represents alphabetic and numeric characters, you can use

`[^[:alnum:]]`  for non alpha numeric so for your goal:

> my target is to work with all kind of characters non alpha numeric and alpha numeric

you can use this expression `[[:alnum:]] | [^[:alnum:]]`

so the awk command will be something like this:

```
awk 'gsub(/("[ ]+|[ ]+")/,"\""){$0=gensub(/"(([[:alnum:]]|[^[:alnum:]])+)"/,"\\1","g")}1' file.csv
```